# Vscode ext create task with new properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

From the docks of vscode there is option if user is running extension which use the task provider API, the extension can contribute a new task (new object) to the task config file -  `task.json`

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api

However, I didn't find any example for it, 
The idea is that if user use my extension and run the task it will create new entry in the task json file, i'll appreciate some reference or code example.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/task-provider

in the https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.taskDefinitions

I saw there is option to add new schema 
`contributes.taskDefinitions` 
is there any full example how to do it ?